# Rails 3: Devise with has_one, Nested attributes not updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am creating a one-to-one relationship to user called user_info.
Below is the working solution.

In user.rb

```
has_one :user_info
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_info, :allow_destroy => true
attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :user_info_attributes
```

In user_info.rb

```
belongs_to :user
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name
```

In devise/registrations/edit.html.erb

```
<% resource.build_user_info if resource.user_info.nil? %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
    ...
    <%= f.fields_for :user_info do |info| %>
        <%= info.text_field :first_name %>
```

I understand that I should not include the build in the view. But I do not want to 'touch' the devise controller or model. This is the easiest way.

Comment: Turns out that the build line is not working properly. Should be `<% resource.build_user_info if resource.user_info.nil? %>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the build line is not working properly in the view.

Should be:
`<% resource.build_user_info if resource.user_info.nil? %>`

Answer (score 1):

Try `:autosave => true` on your call to `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: Should be added to `has_one :user_info, :autosave => true` instead of `accepts_nested attributes_for`. However, this still does not work. It does not save first_name.

Comment: Hmm, ok, why then would you not just add the info to the existing user model? That would be the simplest way to do it.

Comment: It is not good modeling to make a big user model. Typically user model includes many secondary information like website, address, about me, hobbies, etc. etc. Putting it in the same model means that every time you just need to pull list of users or any operation for authentication, you have to pull everything else. It is common and good practice to divide out into 2 models with one-to-one relationship.

Comment: any updates on this question? I'm having the same problem, and have tried working out how to fix is for DAYS but to no avail :(